# Good way to invalidate cache entries when view code changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using Rails 3.2 and looking for a reliable to invalidate cache entries when a piece of view code is changed. In this [article](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) I see that 37signals prefixes the cache key with a version string that is changed each time the view code changes.

For instance if I change `All my...` to `My...`

```
<%= cache ["v1", project] do %>
  <p>All my todo lists:</p>
  [...]
<% end %>
```

I would make sure cache entries are invalidated by changing `v1` to `v2`

```
<%= cache ["v2", project] do %>
  <p>My todo lists:</p>
  [...]
<% end %>
```

Is there a more reliable way to achieve this? I'm concerned we'll forget to update those `vX` string prefixes when changing a partial or helper code called from the inside the cached block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cache_digest](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests). It does exactly what you need: invalidates cache fragments automatically when the view is changed. This way you don't need to track each view version manually.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do this manually. I'm not sure which version of Rails introduced this, but when you use the `cache` view helper it includes a digest of the view you're rendering so that if the view changes, it will invalidate the cache. You can check out the [Rails docs on fragment caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= cahe ['todo', project] do %>
.
.
```

And in controller, after update

```
def update
.
.
if @project.update_attributes(params[:project)
  expire_fragment ['todo', @project] 
  render 'something'
```

in my system, i can see in logs
Write fragment views/show/reports/46-20121016112032 (3.0ms) on report show
next response
Read fragment views/show/reports/46-20121016112032 (0.2ms)
end on report#update
Expire fragment views/show/reports/46-20121016064919 (1.2ms)

Comment: that expires the cache when project changes, but in my case I want to expire the cache not only when the project changes, but also in the cases when the code inside the cache block changes and not necessarily the project

Comment: You can expire all your fragment after update code in deploy scenario

Comment: thanks antiqe that would work, however we deploy several times a day, our fragments would expire too frequently; or maybe we could expire them in a deploy only when some view or helper files have changed